# Search through the file in Unix

Tags: linux, unix, full-text-search

I am a unix/linux newbie here .. total newbie.

I want to search through the large (log) file in Unix environment.
So, I try grep command

```
grep textToSearch fileToSearch
```

However, it just scrolls fast and I can't see all the occurrences.
I saw its done .. probaly with piping that '`grep`' command with some other.  But I don't know what it was.
Basically, I want to be able to run a command, see the output and scroll through that output on my own as I go through the found results.

Please, help ..

Answer (score 1):

I'll say just `cat/bat/less fileToSearch` then just use `/textToSearch`.
with grep you could also pipe to output to cat/bat/less like `grep textToSearch fileToSearch | bat`

Answer (score 1):

You can try grep with -r Recurcivly, -n line number

grep -rn text test.file